# Group items by timeframe

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection `db.activities`, each item of which has a `dueDate`. I need to present data in a following format, which basically a list of activities which are due today and this week:

```
{
  "today": [ 
    { _id: 1, name: "activity #1" ... }, 
    { _id: 2, name: "activity #2" ... } 
  ],
  "thisWeek": [ 
    { _id: 3, name: "activity #3" ... }
  ]
}
```

I managed to accomplish this by simply querying for the last week's activities as a flat list and then grouping them with javascript on the client, but I suspect this is a very dirty solution and would like to do this on server.

Answer (score 1):

look up [`mongo aggregation pipeline`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/).
your aggregation has a match by date, group by date and a maybe a sort/order stage also by date.

lacking the data scheme it will be along the lines of

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ $match: {"duedate": { "$gte" : start_dt, "$lte" : end_dt} } ,
{ $group: {_id: "$duedate", recordid : "$_id" , name: "$name" }, 
{"$sort" : {"_id" : 1} } ]  );
```

if you want 'all' records remove the $match or use `{ $match: {} }` as one does with find.

in my opinion, you cannot aggregate both by day and week within one command. the weekly one may be achieved by projecting duedate using mongos $dayOfWeek. along the lines of

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
{ $match: {"duedate": { "$gte" : start_dt, "$lte" : end_dt} } ,
{ $project :  { dayOfWeek: { $dayOfWeek: "$duedate" } },
{ $group: {_id: "$dayOfWeek", recordid : "$_id" , name: "$name" }, 
{"$sort" : {"_id" : 1} } ]  );
```

check out http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfWeek/